# having particular word records in select query

Tags: mysql

Iam having tables of students and fees.I want to join these two tables

students:

```
student_id      dd_date
  20          2015-12-25
```

Fees:

```
  fee_id     student_id     particulars             due_date

    1           20          Register fee           2015-10-25
    2           20          Late fee               2015-09-28
    3           20          Late Register fee      2015-12-26
    4           20          Application fee        2015-12-28
```

Here i dont want to show the records of dd_date >  due_date having Late word records only.
i want output like this

```
  student_id    fee_id     Particulars       dd_date       due_date

      20          1        Register fee      2015-12-25    2015-10-25
      20          2         Late fee         2015-12-25    2015-09-28
      20          3        Application fee   2015-12-25    2015-12-28
```

Iam writing query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM students S,Fees F 
WHERE F.student_id = S.student_id 
  AND F.particulars  LIKE  '%Late%' 
  AND S.dd_date >F.due_date
```

but its showing only that particular date with late fee only.But i want all records but date query execute only for "Late"  word records

can anyone help

Comment: Your source tables, expectations, and the result do not match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want

```
SELECT * 
FROM students S,Fees F 
WHERE F.student_id = S.student_id 
  AND NOT (F.particulars  LIKE  '%Late%' 
  AND S.dd_date < F.due_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh, if I interpret your question in the right way, then you only need to remove AND F.particulars  LIKE  '%Late%' from the query because this criteria makes sure that only records containing the "Late" word (well, string) are returned.

However, your source tables, expectations, and the result do not match.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use the `s.dd_date > f.due_date` condition for fees having `f.particular LIKE '%late%'`. Try this to achieve that

```
SELECT * 
FROM students s, Fees f 
WHERE f.student_id = s.student_id 
  AND IF(f.particulars LIKE '%Late%', s.dd_date > f.due_date, 1=1)
```